# How to change those formulas with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to modify my script, in order to obtain a similar result like the one posted in the picture.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 


\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{tikz}




\usepackage{subfig}                         

\usepackage{xcolor}



\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 

\usepackage{textcomp} 

\linespread{1.4}                



\frenchspacing 

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}

\usepackage{multicol}




  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}


   \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
   %\usepackage{mathpple}
   %\usepackage{palatino}

   \usepackage{lxfonts}
%   
%   \usepackage{multicol}







 \usepackage{pifont}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \usepackage{tikz}

 \usepackage{bbding}

 \newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }




 \newcommand\yellowbigsqcup[1][\displaystyle]{%
   \fboxrule0pt
   \ifx#1\textstyle\fboxsep-0.6pt\else\fboxsep-1.25pt\fi
   \mathrel{\fcolorbox{white}{yellow}{$#1\bigsqcup$}}}



   \newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
     \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
     \fbox{%
       \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
         \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
         #2
       }%
     }%
     \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
   }

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}


\begin{minipage}{.4\linewidth}
\item $ \dfrac{17}{\colorbox{yellow}{5}}+\dfrac{13}{\colorbox{orange}{6}}-\dfrac{11}{\colorbox{pink}{30}} = \\
\\ \\ \\=\dfrac{17 \cdot 6 +13 \cdot 5 -11  \cdot 1}{\colorbox{green}{30}} \\
\\ \\ \\=\dfrac{\text{\dots\dots} +\text{\dots\dots}- \text{\dots\dots}}{\colorbox{green}{30}} 
\\ \\ \\ =  \dfrac{\text{\dots\dots}}{30} =   \dfrac{\text{\dots\dots}}{\text{\dots\dots}}  \\ $
 \end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
$ \text{m.c.m.}\left(5,6,30\right) =\colorbox{green}{30} \\
$\[\begin{pmatrix}
%prima riga
\colorbox{green}{30}:\textbf{\colorbox{yellow}{5}}=\colorbox{yellow}{\text{6};}
& \colorbox{green}{30}:\textbf{\colorbox{orange}{6}}=\colorbox{orange}{5};
& \colorbox{green}{30}:\textbf{\colorbox{pink}{30}}=\textbf{\colorbox{pink}{1}};  \\
%%seconda riga
%15 \cdot 1 = 15 
%& \text{\dots}\cdot 2 = \text{\dots}
%& \text{\dots}\cdot \text{\dots} = \text{\dots}
\end{pmatrix}\]$
$
\end{minipage}            


\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Regular, green and yellow potatoes. ;-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Why are orange and pink potatoes regular?

Comment: @marmot They looked for me more brown than orange. :-)

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke Now I'm relieved. I started believing I'm eating the wrong potatoes ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Here is an attempt to let `tikz` create potatoes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{subfig}                         
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lxfonts}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{bbding}
%
\linespread{1.4}                
\frenchspacing 
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\newcommand{\cuthere}{%
 \noindent
 \raisebox{-2.8pt}[0pt][0.75\baselineskip]{\small\ding{34}}
 \unskip{\tiny\dotfill}
 }
% marmot code
\newif\ifshowmarmotlabels
\showmarmotlabelstrue
\showmarmotlabelsfalse % comment this line out if you want so see the labels
\newcounter{mynode}\setcounter{mynode}{0}
\newcommand{\ovalnode}[2]{
    \stepcounter{mynode}
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(marmotnode\themynode.base),inner sep=0pt]{%
    \node[ellipse,fill=#1,inner sep=2pt] (marmotnode\themynode) 
    {#2\ifshowmarmotlabels{$^{\themynode}$}\else\fi};}
    }
\newcommand{\underdots}[1]{%
\ifmmode{\underset{\boldsymbol{\scriptscriptstyle\bullet\,\bullet\,\bullet}}{#1}}
\else{$\underset{\boldsymbol{\scriptscriptstyle\bullet\,\bullet\,\bullet}}{\text{#1}}$}
\fi}
% end marmot code
\newcommand\yellowbigsqcup[1][\displaystyle]{%
   \fboxrule0pt
   \ifx#1\textstyle\fboxsep-0.6pt\else\fboxsep-1.25pt\fi
   \mathrel{\fcolorbox{white}{yellow}{$#1\bigsqcup$}}}
\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
     \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
     \fbox{%
       \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
         \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
         #2
       }%
     }%
     \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
   }
%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\hspace*{-1cm}% I moved the things to the left such that they fit better.
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\linewidth}
\item $ \dfrac{17}{\overset{~}{\ovalnode{yellow}{5}}}
+\dfrac{13}{\overset{~}{\ovalnode{orange}{6}}}-
\dfrac{11}{\overset{~}{\ovalnode{pink}{30}}} = \\
\\ \\ \\=\dfrac{17 \cdot 6 +13 \cdot 5 -11\cdot 1}{%
\overset{~}{\ovalnode{green}{\underdots{30}}}} \\
\\ \\ \\=\dfrac{\text{\dots\dots} -\text{\dots\dots}+
\text{\dots\dots}}{\overset{~}{\ovalnode{green}{\underdots{30}}}}
\\ \\ \\ =  \dfrac{\text{\dots\dots}}{30} =   
\dfrac{\text{\dots\dots}}{\text{\dots\dots}}  \\ $
 \end{minipage}%
 \hspace*{-1cm}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
$ \text{m.c.m.}\left(5,6,30\right) =\ovalnode{green}{\underdots{30}} \\
$\[\begin{pmatrix}
%prima riga
\ovalnode{green}{\underdots{30}}:\ovalnode{yellow}{\underdots{\textbf{5}}}
=\ovalnode{yellow}{\underdots{\text{6}}};
& \ovalnode{green}{\underdots{30}}:\ovalnode{orange}{\underdots{\textbf{6}}}
=\ovalnode{orange}{\underdots{5}};
& \ovalnode{green}{\underdots{30}}:\ovalnode{pink}{\underdots{\textbf{30}}}
=\ovalnode{pink}{\underdots{\textbf{1}}};  \\
\end{pmatrix}\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{%
\draw[->,thick] (marmotnode16) to[out=-135, in=45] (marmotnode17);
\draw[->,thick] (marmotnode16) to[out=-90, in=90] (marmotnode20);
\draw[->,thick] (marmotnode16) to[out=-45, in=135] (marmotnode23);}
\end{minipage}            
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT** I adjusted the positions of the minipages, as requested, and added more underdots, and made the arrows curved. If you want to know the labels of the nodes in order to draw more arrows, you may temporarily redefine the ovalnode command to also print the label, say, as a superscript.

**2nd (and hopefully final) EDIT** I moved the potatoes a bit further away from the fraction lines. (And I started cleaning up the code, i.e. removed empty lines and one instance of `\usepackage{tikz}`, and regrouped the preamble. This code still contains a lot of unnecessary packages.) More importantly, I gave the nodes somewhat nicer names, in the previous version they had just numbers, and this may easily collide with other nodes from other packages. I also introduced a new if `\ifshowmarmotlabels` that allows one to determine the names of the nodes. Notice that for some reason the `\overset` command shifts the node numbers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I would like to put the dots under and I'll do as you did ($\underset{\boldsymbol{\cdots}}{\textbf{30}}$). How can I move the tikz image at the top instead of the centre?

Comment: @ryuk Just change both `\begin{minipage}` to `\begin{minipage}[t]`. Will look at the dots later...

Comment: how to increase the distance between denominator and fraction line? (see the pic) thanks

Comment: @ryuk Done. Notice that, as you can easily see from my profile picture, I am very small and fluffy, so I am very slow when typing. Therefore I'd appreciate it very much if you could make further requests in the form of new questions. ;-)

Comment: @ryuk If the solution worked for you please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).