# How to change these formulas?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to modify 2 of formulas like the figure below. Could you help me?

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}[12pt] 
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\linespread{1.5}

\frenchspacing 

\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}

\usepackage{floatflt,epsfig}

\usepackage{multicol}




  \usepackage[a4paper,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,left=1.0cm,right=1.0cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}


$ a^2 = 16 \rightarrow a = \pm 4 =  $

\newpage

$ x \cdot \left( x+3\right)  = 0 \rightarrow $




\end{document}
```

Comment: related links ref. formula 2: [Cases environment without the brace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142671/124842) should help; brackets with `\underbracket` [\overbrace with square bracket](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132527/124842); circle with number [Good way to make \textcircled numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7032/124842)

Comment: What is the `\newpage` command between the last two formulæ for? It doesn't yield the result in your image.

Comment: perhaps also [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405202/121799)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do  it with `pstricks`  and `mathtools` (for the `\underbracket` command).

Unrelated: the `epsfig`has been obsolete for more than 20 years, and should be replaced with `graphicx`. Also, since version 3.10 the language options of `babel` should be loaded with the document class, so language-dependent packages be aware of the language of the document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, italian, svgnames]{article}[12pt]
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} %% to compile with pdflatex --enable-write18 (MiKTeX) or pdflatex --shell-escape (TeX Live, MacTeX))
\newcommand\mathpnode[1]{\pnode[0,\fontdimen22\textfont2]{#1}}

\linespread{1.5}

\frenchspacing
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}

\usepackage{floatflt}%
\usepackage{multicol}

 \usepackage[a4paper, margin=1.0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
$ a^2 = 16 \rightarrow a = \pm 4 = \mathpnode{M}\qquad\begin{aligned}
  \mathpnode{R1} & \mathbf{ + 4} \\[1ex]
  \mathpnode{R2} & \mathbf{ - 4}
\psset{nodesep = 3pt}
\ncline{M}{R1}
\ncline{M}{R2}
\end{aligned} $
\end{pspicture}
\bigskip

$\psset{fillstyle = solid} \underbracket[0.8pt]{\,x\vphantom{)}\,}_{{\substack{\vert\\\pscirclebox[fillcolor = BlanchedAlmond]{1}}}}\! \cdot \underbracket[1pt]{( x+3) }_{\substack{\vert\\\pscirclebox[fillcolor = Aqua!40]{2}}}= 0 \rightarrow \quad\begin{aligned}
 & \raisebox{-0.3\height}{\pscirclebox[fillcolor = BlanchedAlmond]{1}}\quad\mathbf{x = 0}
\\[1ex]
 & \raisebox{-0.3\height}{\pscirclebox[fillcolor = Aqua!40]{2}}\quad\mathbf{x + 3\rightarrow x = -3}
\end{aligned}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer! How can I enable "shell escape" (or "write18") in order to run the code? thanks a lot.

Comment: @ryuk: What are your distribution  and  editor?

Comment: I use texmaker.

Comment: The editor, yes. But the distribution: MiKTeX, TeX Live, MacTeX?

Comment: It could be TeX live (I use ubuntu)

Comment: Sure. Go to the `Options -> Configure TeXmaker` menu; click on the `Commands` icon (it should be opened by default) and in the second line (for `pdflatex`), type `pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and validate. ( I guess it works the same way for all platforms).

Comment: now it works! thanks a lot! One last question...I prefer the standalone format compared to the article format, because I would like to create the formula in pdf and insert it in another latex file at a later time, but typing "\ documentclass [border = 5mm] {standalone}" instead of "\ documentclass [a4paper, 12pt, italian, svgnames] {article} [12pt] "an error appears.

Comment: I guess this is because the two groups are in different paragraphs (there's a blank line). Doy you want to group the groups ;o) ?

Comment: yes, i want it .

Comment: @ryuk: I'll try to see that tomorrow to find a solution – I also have problems with `standalone` and these two equations grouped.